# Updating devise object without form, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails and devise. It seams the only way to update a user object is to go through the form. Even when I use console or save(false) the devise objects doesn't seem to be working.

I don't want to display the new and confirm password unless a user clicks a link that says change password. This then changes a boolean on the user to true, and redirects to the user page and then an if/else/end shows the appropiate code.

The problem is that the first change_password does get set, but the second will not change it back. Crazy.

model

```
devise :registerable, :database_authenticatable, :recoverable,
     :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name, :change_password

 has_many :analytics
 has_many :answers

 before_save :change_password_to_false


 def change_password_to_false
   self.change_password = false
 end
```

controller

```
def change_password
  player = Player.find(current_player.id)
  player.change_password = true
  player.save(false)    
  redirect_to edit_player_registration_path 
end

def keep_password_the_same
  player = Player.find(current_player.id)
  player.change_password = false
  player.save(false)    
  redirect_to edit_player_registration_path
end
```

view

```
<% if current_player.change_password?  %>
    <h4><%= link_to "Keep Password The Same", keep_password_the_same_path  %></h4>
    <%= render 'change_password', :f => f %>
<% else %>
    <h4><%= link_to "Change Password", change_password_path  %></h4>
<% end %>
```

## Update

There were a few problems with the code but codevoice was able to get me in the right direction. I thought save(false) was bypassing callbacks too but that was not the case. So every time the user was updated even when the user was updated with save(false) it `change_password` was getting set to false.

The second thing was giving the user the ability to remove the change password fields if they decided they didn't want to change it. So in the callback I just check if the `change_password` field was just changed to true and then I don't do anything. If the password was already true and the user was just updated then you can reset it to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion your `change_pasword` attribute will be alweys `false` beacasue you use `before_save :change_password_to_false`. Thats mean that you are changeing `change_password` to `false` every time you save the `Player` model

Comment: yeah pretty much, I thought save(false) bypassed callbacks too but was wrong.